# Translate/Separate IQueryable expressions?

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

consider the following scenario:

```
public class DBEntry {
  public string Id;
}

public class ComputedEntry {
  public string Id;
  public int ComputedIndex;
}

IQueryable<DBEntry> databaseQueryable; // Somewhere hidden behind the API
IQueryable<ComputedEntry> entryQueryable; // Usable with the API
```

Let's assume each `DBEntry` has a unique `Id` and not much else. A `ComputedEntry` has a 1:n relationship with `DBEntry`, meaning that a `DBEntry`can be expanded into more than a single `ComputedEntry`during execution of the query.

Now, I am trying to query `entryQueryable` to get a range of computed indices, e.g:

```
entryQueryable.Where(dto => dto.ComputedIndex < 10 && dto.Id == "some-id");
```

What I'm looking for is a way of separating the given query expression to only push down the relevant parts of the query to the `databaseQueryable`. In the example above something like this should happen (probably in the implementation of `IQueryableProvider.Execute` when using the `entryQueryable`):

```
var results = databaseQueryable.Where(e => e.Id == "some-id").ToList();
int i = 0;
return results.Select(e => new ComputedEntry(e.Id, i++));
```

So basically I'd like the query to be separated and the relevant/compatible parts should be pushed down to the `databaseQueryable`.

The obvious question would be: How should I approach this? I tried to figure out a way of separating the expression with an `ExpressionVisitor`, but haven't been very successful here and it seems like this is a rather complex task.

Any ideas? Maybe there is an already existing method of optimizing/translating the query I am not aware of? I have looked through the documentation but couldn't find anything useful here.

Many thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Maybe [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/) might help?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. What will translating a query help you achieve? And what do you actually mean by it? Seems to me that you have already done it.

Comment: @M.Azyoksul Not quite. Take a look at the two queries in my example. The first one is supposed to be used with the API of my application, but internally this needs to be two distinct queries, see the second code block. One needs to be pushed down to the database (not really a database, I just called it that here to make its purpose more obvious) and the other one is used to filter the expanded results of the queried items.

Eg: dbQueryable produces an item with Id "test", then this item may be expanded 20 times and this result set is what I'd like to expose to the API.

Comment: @RichardDeeming Very interesting. Will definitely take a look at it, thank you!